# SQL only return values where first letter is between A-Z

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to return only values from a field that have the first letter between A-Z,

I have tried using the below but this only does one letter at a time.

```
UPPER(LEFT(AD_ADDR,1)) like 'A%'
```

The other characters will be 0-10, which I want to exclude but are formatted as strings, so using IS_INTEGER doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want the first character to be only uppercase (A-Z) or is lowercase also an option (ignore-case or case-insensitive) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `RLIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE AD_ADDR RLIKE '[a-zA-Z].*';
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use [`LIKE` of Snowflake's SQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like):

> Allows case-sensitive matching of strings based on comparison with a pattern.

```
WHERE AD_ADDR LIKE '[A-Z]%'
```

The pattern `'[A-Z]%'` explained:

- `[A-Z]` is a regular-expression matching the first character to an uppercase character range from A to Z
- `%` is a wildcard to match any following sequence like explained below

> `LIKE` pattern matching covers the entire string. To match a sequence anywhere within a string, start and end the pattern with `%`.

Comment: According to Snowflake's docs this `LIKE` expression answers exactly what was questioned for: a predicate matching only the first character to be in a given range. Thus I elaborated, linked the docs - hope this improvement is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

UPPER(LEFT(AD_ADDR, 1)) IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')